# CHS of hard drive, which head is Head 1?

Tags: hard-drive

[image]

Suppose that the uppermost head is head 0, which head in the picture is head 1? The other side of head 0 or next platter? I think head 1 should be on the next platter so that multiple heads can be read at the same time.

Comment: The answer can be anything the manufacturer wants it to be.  The heads could even be in interleaved order or grey code order.  There is no standard for this, and modern drives don't even use CHS in any physically meaningful way.

Comment: Head #1 would be the other side of the platter that uses head #0.  Only one R/W head can be used at a time.  Multiple heads cannot be active at once because there's a servo feedback loop.

Comment: Actually, with modern drives, they probably are all read and written in parallel, with them all writing at once.  Some disks even have a servo platter.

Comment: @user10489 -- Regarding your speculation on "*parallel*" operation, see user10762593's comment to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54725827/is-there-any-disk-supports-parallel-reading

Comment: When I talk about all the heads being used in parallel, they are not being used separately.  They would all be participating in a single I/O operation and all of their data streams combined into a single data stream, similar to but not exactly like bits in the same byte.  (The mapping is likely to be a lot messier.)   So in that context, it's multiple platters of a single disk device with a unified data stream, not separate disks operating in parallel.

Comment: @user10489 -- Based on my first-hand experience with developing disk-controller firmware, your guessing is not feasible.  ECC and error handling would be a nightmare.  Spreading each block over several surfaces multiplies the chances for bad blocks. Simply not practical IMO.

Comment: Perhaps this was more common when disks had 8-11 heads, which is a rarity now.

Comment: @user10489 -- Back in the day "*when disks had 8-11 heads ... was more common*" such a scheme would be even more implausible since electronics were more expensive, bulkier, and consumed more power.  So what you "*talk about*" probably never existed as a commercial product.  An experimental, one-off device or imaginary device is not worth discussing.